# get_access_token() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, typeerror, self

I'm not very experienced programming in Python but I've also seen in several posts that this problem might be solved by adding `self` to the method definition. The problem is that I actually already did this right from the beginning. This is the code I'm using:

```
### API MANAGER ###

class api_manager():
    import requests, time, pandas as pd
    #from ipython.display import display, HTML
    
#    heroes = []
#    items = []
#    token = ''
#    url = ""
    
    def __init__(self, api_identifier = 1):
        
        test_api_url = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/"
        live_api_url = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_205790/"

        self.heroes = []
        self.items = []
        self.token = ''
        self.url = ""

        if api_identifier == 1:
            self.url = live_api_url
        else:
            self.url = test_api_url
        
        self.get_access_token()
        self.initialize_heroes()
        self.initialize_items()
        pass
    
    
    def get_access_token(self):
        with open("conf/access.config") as file:
            self.token = file.read().split(":")[1]
        
        file.close
        pass
    
    
    def initialize_heroes(self):
        response = self.requests.get(self.url + "GetHeroes/v1/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token)
        hero_list = response.json()
        
        for hero_id in range(len(hero_list['result']['heroes'])):
            self.heroes.append([hero_list['result']['heroes'][hero_id]['id'], hero_list['result']['heroes'][hero_id]['localized_name'], hero_list['result']['heroes'][hero_id]['name'].replace('npc_dota_hero_', "").replace("_", " ")])
        
        self.heroes.sort()
        heroes_df = self.pd.DataFrame(self.heroes, columns=["ID", "Hero", "Hero Tag"])
        self.pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
        
        #display(HTML(heroes_df.to_html(index = False)))
        pass
    
    
    def initialize_items(self):
        response = self.requests.get(self.url + "GetGameItems/v1/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token)
        item_list = response.json()
        
        for item_id in range(len(item_list['result']['items'])):
            self.items.append([item_list['result']['items'][item_id]['id'], item_list['result']['items'][item_id]['localized_name'], response.json()['result']['items'][item_id]['name']])
        
        self.items.sort()
        items_df = self.pd.DataFrame(self.items, columns=["ID", "Item", "Item Tag"])
        self.pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
        
        #display(HTML(items_df.to_html(index = False)))
        pass
    
    
    def get_match_details(match_id, self):
        response = self.requests.get(self.url + "GetMatchDetails/V001/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token + "&match_id=" + str(match_id))
        print(response.json())
        pass
        
        
    def get_match_details_in_range(match_id, match_id_upper_bound, self):
        for next_match_id in range(match_id, match_id_upper_bound):
            response = self.requests.get(self.url + "GetMatchDetails/V001/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token + "&match_id=" + str(next_match_id))
            print(response.json())
            self.time.sleep(1.05)
        pass
```

And this is the error I'm getting in Python3 console run in Windows cmd:

```
>>> instance = api_manager()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Dropbox\DotA 2 WebAPI Development\Executable Python Files\dota_api_manager.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.get_access_token()
TypeError: get_access_token() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong. I already tried different things in my code but never got it to actually work. There was one moment when the code executed properly and I could actually call the method `get_match_details()` but I got an error because the `url` parameter was not set for whatever reason, although it should have been initialized right in the beginning of `__init__()`.

Thanks in advance for your help and let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: I imagine this is not the whole code and the `get_access_token` being called in not the `get_access_token` which we see here. Try to search for a different `get_access_token` somewhere in your code. One that does not take any arguments.

Comment: That error is because you called `self.get_access_token()` at some place, an argument was passed in when the method doesn't accept any. However, when I directly copy and paste your code, it works up until the point I don't have your config file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for bringing that to attention. I totally forgot that I was working in a file that was called exactly like the module which is why I had to copy and rename it to properly import and instantiate it. But I totally forgot to update the code in the copied file I used in the console. Now I'm getting some weird error in the JSON module in initialize_heroes(), so time for a new post I guess..